# Bootstrap Multi Stage Form - Gather user input w/ JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I am working with a multi stage form, and I would like to collect the data that the user has been entering to create a summary page at the end.

When the user hits the “Next” button on this form I want to grab any data they entered and display it on the next stage of the form; **using jQuery**. I also need to store these values to send to a DB when the user submits the form after the summary.

Here is an example of the form that I am working on:

```
<fieldset>
    <div class="form-top">
        <div class="form-top-left">
            <h2>Servers</h2>
            <h3>Tell us about the servers you need</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="form-top-right">
            <img src="assets/images/icons/select_servers.png" class="form-icon">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-bottom">
        <div class="form-group">
            <p>Does this quote include servers?</p>
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="serverRadios" id="formIncludeServers" value="Yes">
                <label class="form-check-label">Yes</label>
                <div class="reveal-if-active">
                    <label for="select-servers">How many do you need?</label><br />
                    <label for="pro-server" class="form-partner-label">Pro Server</label>
                    <input type="text" name="pro-quantity" class="form-proserver-qty form-control" id="form-partner-pro" value="0">
                    <br />
                    <label for="device-9104" class="form-partner-label">Mini Server</label>
                    <input type="text" name="mini-quantity" class="form-miniserver-qty form-control" id="form-partner-mini" value="0">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="serverRadios" id="formExcludeServers" value="No" checked="">
                <label class="form-check-label">No</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-previous">Previous</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-next">Next</button>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: have you written code to store into db?

Comment: I have a PHP script that stores the user's information into the DB when they register an account. In this scenario, however, I need to collect the information prior to submitting the form and display it within a summary fieldset.

Comment: You want to submit via ajax or form?

Comment: The submission should be via the form. I am not using ajax for this project.

Comment: Are you using bootstrap css?

Comment: Yes. The form has been built as a multistage bootstrap form.